# Milliseconds to Hours(more than 24)

Tags: java, time

I have a system that sum up all the hours(converted to milliseconds), if that hour is more than 24 hours(eg, 26 hours), it will back to `02:00:00` instead of `26:00:00`.

```
totH = parser.parse(totalH);
totHTotal += totH.getTime(); // assume totHTotal gets 93600000.
totalHours = parser.format(new Date(totHTotal));
System.out.println(totalHours); // this will output 02:00:00 but I want this to output 26:00:00.
```

Can somebody help me, thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) or do the arithmetic.

1 hour: 3 600 000ms
1 minute: 60 000ms
1 second: 1 000ms

You can run it here: https://repl.it/GLLH/9

```java
import java.time.Duration;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Using math");
    long millsMath = 93631000;

    long hoursMath = millsMath / 3600000;
    long minutesMath = (millsMath % 3600000) / 60000;
    long secondsMath = (millsMath % 60000) / 1000;

    String outMath = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hoursMath, minutesMath, secondsMath);
    System.out.println(outMath);



    System.out.println("\nUsing Duration");
    Duration dur = Duration.ofMillis(93631000);

    long hoursDur   = dur.toHours();
    long minutesDur = dur.minusHours(hoursDur).toMinutes();
    long secondsDur = dur.minusHours(hoursDur).minusMinutes(minutesDur).getSeconds();

    String outDur = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hoursDur, minutesDur, secondsDur);

    System.out.println(outDur);
  }
}
```

output:

```
Using math
26:00:31

Using Duration
26:00:31
```

Comment: It works! But I also want that this will be displayed as 26:00:00,  and if the milliseconds is equivalent to 26:25:00, how to do display that? Thank you

Comment: I need this variable as  26:00:00 because I need to parse this again so that I can do arithmetic operation, subtract to a time.

Comment: take the remainder of the time in mills using % 3600000 and subtract it from the time mills, I'll edit the code

update: edit done.

Comment: I still got 26.

Comment: you could literally just create a string.... using something like dur.toHours() + ":00:00"

Comment: Yeah, I get that but what if the milliseconds is something like 96000000, how to get its minutes? Thank you

Comment: I'll edit the code to a more logical way of doing what you are asking.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you. It solved my problem. But I got another problem if you don't mind me asking again. Let's say I got 26:30:00 and I will subtract 01:40:00 to it, I got 00:50:00. I want here to get 24:50:00. Can you still help me with this? Thank you for your time mate.

Comment: total = parser.parse(totalHours); // totalHours is 26:30:00
LUT = parser.parse(OverAllTotalx); // OverAllTotalx is  01:40:00
long wHours = total.getTime() - LUT.getTime();
String totalWHours = parser.format(new Date(wHours)); // I got  00:50:00 here, I want it 24:50:00.

Comment: You just reverse engineer it. You substring the hours, parse it into a long and multiply it by 3600000. Substring the minutes, parse it to long, multiply it by 60000. Substring the seconds, parse it to long, multiply it by 1000. Add all of these up and do the arithmetic, then print the formatted result back the same way you did at first.

Comment: I'm new to Java, can you do it for me? It's a great help.

Comment: I noticed that, but since I'm a firm believer in the practical method, I recommend you give it a try. go look at the Long.parseLong(String s) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String- and String.substring(int startIndex, int endIndex) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int- functions documentation if needed

Comment: I solved the second problem, I convert  26:30:00 and 00:50:00 to minutes then subtract the since it's already a whole number and multiply the difference to the rate and parseLong the difference and convert back to mills then using you formula for getting the time which I get the 24:50:00. Thank you very much!